# Missing Server Side Dependencies Errors on Search Service Administration WebParts

Tags: web-part, migration, health-analyzer

I am trying to resolve some [MissingWebPart] errors from the CA Health Analyzer, from a site migrated from 2007 to 2010 with a database detach/reattach. The set of errors all refer to the WebParts on the Search Service Application: Search Administration page (General Application Settings > Farm Search Administration > Search Service Application).

Navigating to this page in Central Administration and reanalyzing the health check causes the issue to disappear (Per [an MSDN Social post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/b43c6db2-467d-439a-bc35-6a00c11b4b8d) regarding the exact same problem)... until the next day when it shows back up.

## Edit:

> This only reappeared once. Since then it has remained removed from the Health Analyzer, which is strange to say the least.

In SharePoint Designer you can see that all of these WebParts display the same notification in the WebPart Gallery (Note the blue 'i' icons):

[image: Some of the WebParts. Note the blue 'i' icons.]

And when you click on any of them they display:

[image: "This file has been modified from the site's definition."]

It's notable that a number of other WebParts that I would consider "core" WebParts also display this message (though they don't display any errors in the Health Analyzer).

If I revert these WebParts to their definition (from the ribbon in SPD), will this fix this?

And, what is the root cause of this? Is it because they were migrated from 2007, so they're old versions of the WebParts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your features and webparts, you can use scripts to remove faulty features after an upgrade. Also, webparts may be embedded in solutions that were not installed in the 2010 environment.

http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/ comes to mind, and has been praised by the SharePoint community. It uses the Sharepoint Object Model, so it's supported by Microsoft.

Also follow these threads: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulking/archive/2011/10/05/removing-missingfeature-database-amp-missingwebpart-webpart-class-errors-from-sharepoint-2010.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/allenwang/archive/2011/10/09/sharepoint-2010-missing-server-side-dependencies.aspx

Comment: These are not web parts from any 3rd party features. These are SharePoint OOTB web parts. I had already seen that last article, and navigating to those pages rectified the Health Analyzer issue. The real questions here are "What happens if you revert these web parts to their definition via SPD?" and "Why are these web parts saying they've been customized from the site definition / What causes this?" (the latter I'm sure is because of the migration due to the date stamps).

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you running? Because according to the second article the OOTB webparts being "Missing Server side Dependencies" seem to be a bug up to Aug 2011.

Comment: The server is on the October 2010 CU. Thank you for the second link. I'm still curious about what happens if you revert the web parts to their definition, without trying it (there is no test environment, only production). But +1 for the link.

Comment: You can always copy/paste or export webparts for backup. Reset def of a webpart you know isn't in use. If something doesnt work out, revert back to the original webpart by renaming it. I'm curious to see what happens too. In the wp library properties in SPD you can check the versioning, so you revert a file back to it's original version. Just an option.

Comment: If you rename the file instead of using versioning, would you have to change the references in your master pages? The pre-2010 v3UI masters?

Comment: No webparts should be located in your OOTB masterpage. Do you have webparts embedded in your masterpage?

Comment: I meant more like the assembly references. And no.

Comment: I don't think you would have you rereference the assemblies.

Comment: For the link that declares this as a bug, you win sir.

Answer (score -2):

the problem is that the GUID's need to be re-registered. Best bet is to delete the webparts. Add new 2010 webparts and run SQL queries to remove the old GUIDs from the DB.

Comment: -1 Directly interacting with the content DB will cause your installation to be no longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: @Stuart Pegg This is true. That is not an option.